# pthread RWlock quesion

Tags: c, pthreads

I am using a translator because I am not good at English.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_rwlock_t R_Lock;
int ac=0;  

void* RD_LOCK(void* arg) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&R_Lock);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    printf("%d\n",ac); // ac is global variable 0                                                                                                                                                                                                
    sleep(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock); 
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
void* WR_LOCK(void* arg) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&R_Lock);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    printf("RW LCOK\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ac++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    printf("%d\n",ac);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    sleep(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock);                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
void DO_RW_LCOK(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    pthread_t RW[3];                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    pthread_rwlock_init(&R_Lock, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    pthread_create(&RW[0], NULL, RD_LOCK,NULL); //==0 thread                                                                                                                                                                                     
    pthread_create(&RW[1], NULL, RD_LOCK,NULL); //==1 thread                                                                                                                                                                                     
    pthread_create(&RW[2], NULL, WR_LOCK,NULL); //==2 thread                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&R_Lock);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    pthread_join(RW[i],NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
int main(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    DO_RW_LCOK();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}  

void* RD_LOCK(void* arg) {

  pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&R_Lock);
  printf("%d\n",ac); // ac is global variable 0
  sleep(1);
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock); }

void* WR_LOCK(void* arg) {

  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&R_Lock);
  ac++;
  printf("%d\n",ac);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock);
}
int main(){
  DO_RW_LOCK();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to execute 3 threads.

0,1 thread used readlock and 2 thread used writelcok.

My prediction after the program runs After the 0,1 thread, 2 thread was executed.

However, the run order is 2thread,0thread,1thread

I don't understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are always unpredictable. So the order may really change and be unexpected.
In order to guarantee that your threads will be in the order that you want them to be, add a wait option which will make the thread wait if the other threads are not done. Just use wait and notify.
I did not get which thread type you are using but here is a pseudocode.

```
Lock waitAndNotify;
int rdDone = 0;
void* RD_LOCK(void* arg) {
  pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&R_Lock);
  rdDone++;
  notify(waitAndNotify);
  printf("%d\n",ac); // ac is global variable 0
  sleep(1);
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock); }

void* WR_LOCK(void* arg) {

  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&R_Lock);
  if(rdDone!=2)
    wait(waitAndNotify);
  ac++;
  printf("%d\n",ac);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&R_Lock);
}
```

Comment: Can't i set the order with the read lock and write lock only?

Comment: Nope, the threads will always start in different orders. You are not calling a function, you are creating a thread.  Unfortunately!

Comment: @KUD No, you can't. You need a signaling mechanism for that purpose. Every solution only using a single lock will be unreliable.